# How to get rid of white 1px line on bottom and right side of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want a `JPanel` which is currently black but will change color, inside of a `JFrame`. I only set the size of the panel and then call `.pack` on my frame, but an ugly white 1px line appears on the bottom and right side of my frame. Why is that and how can I fix it?
I am currently running Windows 11.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    
    private static GamePanel gamePanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        createWindow();
        
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        window.add(gamePanel);
        
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    private static JFrame window;
    
    private static void createWindow() {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("My Game");
        window.setResizable(false);
    }
    
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    
    // Screen settings
    final int originalTileSize = 16;
    final int scaleFactor = 3;
    
    final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scaleFactor;
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int screenWidth = maxScreenCol * tileSize;
    final int screenHeight = maxScreenRow * tileSize;
    
    // --- Constructor ---
    GamePanel () {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    }
    
    public int getScreenWidth () {
        return screenWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't notice the problem using JDK11 on Windows 10. Comments about the code: 1) Make sure the frame and its components are created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. 2) Swing components are double buffered by default.

Comment: I forgot to mention i am running Windows 11 and JDK 18. I'm fairly new to programming and have not yet fully understood how threads work, i thought this is handled by default, if not how do i make sure the components are created on the EDT? Also thank's for the info.

Comment: Do you have Windows screen scaling > 100%?  If so, that can cause drawing artifacts.

Comment: `how do i make sure the components are created on the EDT?` - Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). All the tutorial examples follow this approach;.

Comment: Indeed it was the screen scaling, i had it to 125% by default, setting it to 100 fixed the problem. Thank's a lot